# How to save / load MKCoordinateRegion?

Tags: ios, mapkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Persisting CoreLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813166/persisting-corelocation)

I understand the problem outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537263/why-mkcoordinatespan-changes).  My question is how do you get around this?  There has got to be a simple way to save a MKCoordinateRegion and load it later on with having it be exactly the same.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)gotoRememberedLocation:(BOOL)animated
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    //Set the user coordinate to the last known coord
    coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([((NSNumber*)[prefs stringForKey:@"Latitude"]) doubleValue],
                                       [((NSNumber*)[prefs stringForKey:@"Longitude"]) doubleValue]);

    //Set the saved span values
    span.longitudeDelta = [((NSNumber*)[prefs stringForKey:@"SpanLongitude"]) doubleValue];
    span.latitudeDelta = [((NSNumber*)[prefs stringForKey:@"SpanLatitude"]) doubleValue];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
    [map setRegion:region animated:animated];
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'll even take a not-so-simple approach...